# How to update/ make a view updatable in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, sql-view

I have created a view via:

```
CREATE VIEW product_prices
AS SELECT Name, Price
FROM Products;
```

And I need to update it so prices under £10 are made 10% bigger apart from ones that are in category 3. These need to be looked up in a separate SELECT statement.

I have got this code so far but I'm getting the 1443 error that the definition of the view won't let me update it. How do I make it an updatable view?

```
UPDATE product_prices
SET Price = Price * 1.1
WHERE Name != (SELECT Name FROM Products WHERE Category_ID = 3)
AND Price < 10;
```

Comment: Read the manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/view-updatability.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `join` instead of `<>`:

```
UPDATE product_prices pp LEFT JOIN
       Products p
       ON p.name = pp.anme and p.Category_ID = 3
    SET pp.Price = pp.Price * 1.1
WHERE p.Name IS NULL AND pp.Price < 10;
```

The issue is the operation on the table being updated, not the view definition.

Comment: Thank you! Everywhere online was saying what not to do, you have saved me :D